# Help identifying possible fossil found in coastal northern Iran

Tags: species-identification, fossil

This was found in Jangels near by the sea, in North Iran:

[image]

Comment: can  you add something for scale or give the dimentions and please edit this into your question.

Comment: Pictures from the side and bottom would also help. Having said that the term "echinoderm" springs to mind. Which one, I have no idea.